# Как включить таймер на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возможно в заголовке я не ясно выразился 
Так вот мне нужно что бы в программе с определенной точки начался отсчет времени и по истечении времени выполнилась определенная функция (то есть запущена программа пошел отсчет после 10 секунд выполни функцию и финиш)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуй, думаю это тебе поможет.

```
import threading

Timer = threading.Timer(timeout, func)
Timer.start()

# timeout - время в секундах
# func - функция которая выполнится после истечения времени
# Или можно
```

Это самое простое решение этой задачи.
И на всякий случай ссылка на инфу по [threading](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-python_part_9/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы ищите функцию [sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) из модуля [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html).

Вот пример ее использования:

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(10):
    print("hi! i am value #"+str(i)+" next value appears after 5 seconds.")
    sleep(5)
```

Если вы хотите сделать это параллельно с чем-то (или что-то параллельно этому), то вам уже нужен модуль [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)